Телеграм бот выдает непонятную ошибку
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?
Пишу своего бота для анонимных сообщений и он иногда просто ломается. Я не могу понять почему, я потыкал абсолютно весь функционал своего бота, но так и не смог понять когда происходит ошибка, вот код бота (через сохранение message в файл я собирался реализовавать базу данных):
import telebot
import pickle 
import logging
from telebot import types
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot= telebot.TeleBot(tg_api)
n=0
bot.delete_webhook()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    dictionary=message
    with open(f'{message.from_user.id}_start.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, f)
    with open(f'{message.from_user.id}_start.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        loaded_dict = pickle.load(f)
        #print(loaded_dict)
        #print("\n")
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn2=types.KeyboardButton("Отправить анонимно файл админам")
    markup.row(btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}, теперь ты можешь анонимно отправить файл админам ",reply_markup=markup)

    
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=['send'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправляй файл (фото, видео, кружочки, голосовое сообщение) \nЕсли нужно скинуть текст отправляйте скрин ")
    global n
    n=1
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo','video','document',"audio",'voice',"video_note"])
    def get_content(message):
        global n
        if n==0:
            bot.reply_to(message, "Чтобы отправить файл админам нажми /send")
        if n==1:
            if message.photo != None :
                bot.reply_to(message, "Фото анонимно отправлено админам")
            elif message.video != None:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Видео анонимно отправлено админам")
            elif message.document != None:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Файл анонимно отправлен админам")
            elif message.audio != None:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Аудио анонимно отправлно админам")
            elif message.voice != None:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Гс анонимно отправлен админам")
            elif message.video_note != None:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Кружок анонимно отправлен админам")
            else:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Отправлено админам")
            #print(message.from_user.username)
            id_tg_ = str(message.from_user.id)
            TO_CHAT_ID = "id" # айди пользователя ,которому должен приходить файл
            TO_CHAT_ID2 = "id" # айди пользователя ,которому должен приходить файл
            bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id) 
            bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID2, message.chat.id, message.message_id) 
            n=0
        



@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Команды бота: \n 1) /start - запустить бота \n 2) /help - отображение всех команд \n 3) /send - отправить файл админам')

@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
    if message.text=="Отправить анонимно файл админам":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправляй файл (фото, видео, кружочки, голосовое сообщение) \nЕсли нужно скинуть текст отправляйте скрин")
        global n
        n=1
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo','video','document',"audio",'voice',"video_note"])
        
        def get_content(message):
            global n
            if n==0:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Чтобы отправить файл админам нажми /send")
            if n==1:
                if message.photo != None :
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Фото анонимно отправлено админам")
                elif message.video != None:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Видео анонимно отправлено админам")
                elif message.document != None:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Файл анонимно отправлен админам")
                elif message.audio != None:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Аудио анонимно отправлно админам")
                elif message.voice != None:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Гс анонимно отправлен админам")
                elif message.video_note != None:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Кружок анонимно отправлен админам")
                else:
                    bot.reply_to(message, "Отправлено админам")
                #print(message.from_user.username)
                id_tg_ = str(message.from_user.id)
                TO_CHAT_ID = "id" # айди пользователя ,которому должен приходить файл
                TO_CHAT_ID2 = "id" # айди пользователя ,которому должен приходить файл
                bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id) 
                bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID2, message.chat.id, message.message_id) 
                n=0
            
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message,"Пиши команды, вот список /help и учитывай какие файлы принимают админы ")


bot.polling(non_stop=True)

И вот код ошибки:
PS E:\бот тг> & C:/Users/suslo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.12.exe "e:/бот тг/main2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 507, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1428, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 331, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 300, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 474, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 507, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1428, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 331, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 300, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\бот тг\main2.py", line 105, in <module>
    bot.polling(non_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1198, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1273, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1235, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 8945, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "e:\бот тг\main2.py", line 21, in start
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}, теперь ты можешь анонимно отправить файл админам ",reply_markup=markup)
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1775, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 273, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\suslo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 682, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))


Ну, коннекта нет, судя по всему

А с чем нет коннекта? Ведь в боте все работает вроде бы, и я ничего не подключаю. Единственная зацепка, я один раз пока искал ошибку написал /start бот заигнорил, написал еще раз он выдал сообщение и выдал вроде эту же ошибку

Я бы для начала избавился от вложенных обработчиков,  это прям вообще не хорошо. Только из-за этого могут вылезти всякие баги и непредсказуемые эффекты.

Вложенный обработчик это вот это?
@bot.message_handler(commands=['send'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправляй файл (фото, видео, кружочки, голосовое сообщение) \nЕсли нужно скинуть текст отправляйте скрин ")
    global n
    n=1
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo','video','document',"audio",'voice',"video_note"])
    def get_content(message):

